# Unable to use mongoid_slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, slug

I am learning ROR with mongodb for last 10 days. I am unable to get mongoid_slug work during  installation. Please see what I get at http://pastebin.com/Gtjzx3Xp

I have gem mongoid (3.0.4, 3.0.1). My Gemfile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem "mongoid", "~> 3.0.0"

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'mongoid_slug'
gem 'stringex'
```

Then,

```
$> bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mongoid":
  In Gemfile:
    mongoid_slug (>= 0) ruby depends on
      mongoid (~> 2.0.0.beta7) ruby

    mongoid (3.0.1)
```

My Controller is:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Slug
  field :name, type: String
  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String
  validates :title,  :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 10 }
  has_many :comments
  slug :name
end
```

On webpage, when I run, I get:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Mongoid::Slug
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Does mongoid_slug not work with current version fo mongoid? How can I get it work?

Answer (score 2):

The [RubyGems version of mongoid_slug](http://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid_slug) appears to be out of date; that one wants Mongoid 2.0 (`mongoid ~> 2.0`) and that's where your `bundle install` error comes from. The [GitHub version](https://github.com/hakanensari/mongoid-slug) appears to be [for Mongoid 3.0](https://github.com/hakanensari/mongoid-slug/blob/master/mongoid_slug.gemspec#L17):

```
s.add_dependency 'mongoid',  '~> 3.0'
```

So you could try using this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongoid_slug', :git => 'git://github.com/hakanensari/mongoid-slug.git'
```

to use the GitHub version.

Comment: Thats right. I had the same observation and I sent email to Hakan letting him know. As his Git version expects 3.0. However after using your suggestion, by using gem directly from git, I see the installation error disappeared, but I still get the  Routing Error

uninitialized constant Mongoid::Slug
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: Yes, I get /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/mongoid-slug-8b5a112d8324  when I run bundle show mongoid_slug

Comment: There seem to have similar issue https://github.com/hakanensari/mongoid-slug/issues/30 but the solution suggested there does not work in my case

Comment: @JVK: And have you restarted your application after rebundling?

Comment: I did try gem 'mongoid_slug', :git => 'https://github.com/hakanensari/mongoid-slug', :require => 'mongoid/slug' but that did not make any difference

Comment: I'm at a loss then. Have you opened a ticket with the author?

Comment: Yes I have sent email to Hakan and waiting for his reply.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer here is that your mongoid_slug version is too low. Try specifying the most recent version in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mongoid_slug', '0.10.0'
```

And then `bundle update mongoid_slug` and see if that fixes the problem.